# Revit API cannot run the external command

Tags: c#, autodesk, revit-api, revit

I am currently trying to create a Autodesk Revit add in, which check the geometry of a room. I am struggling to do this due to an error which says "Revit cannot run the external command. AutodeskRevit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException.   HelloWorld.Class1 does not inherit IExternalCommand.

*Sorry I'm new to C# and Autodesk Revit*

So I am assuming the IExternalCommand needs to be inputted into the code to run the command. When I do so include the IExternalComand I receive a visual studio error saying "Class1 does not implement interface member 'IExternalCommand.Execute(ExternalCommandData, ref string, ElementSet)".

Here is my code:

```
    using System;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.Creation;
using Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture;


namespace HelloWorld
{
    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)]
    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Regeneration(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.RegenerationOption.Manual)]
    class Class1 :IExternalCommand
    {



        public void GetRoomDimensions(Autodesk.Revit.DB.Document doc, Room room)
        {
            String roominfo = "Room dimensions:\n";
            // turn on volume calculations:
            using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc, "Turn on volume calculation"))
            {
                t.Start();
                AreaVolumeSettings settings = AreaVolumeSettings.GetAreaVolumeSettings(doc);
                settings.ComputeVolumes = true;
                t.Commit();
            }

            roominfo += "Vol: " + room.Volume + "\n";
            roominfo += "Area: " + room.Area + "\n";
            roominfo += "Perimeter: " + room.Perimeter + "\n";
            roominfo += "Unbounded height: " + room.UnboundedHeight + "\n";
            TaskDialog.Show("Revit", roominfo);

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IExternalCommand` runs from the `Execute` method.  You need to have an `Execute` method defined in your class. From there you can call your `GetRoomDimensions` method

```
public Result Execute(
  ExternalCommandData commandData, 
  ref string message, 
  ElementSet elements)
{
    UIApplication application = commandData.Application;
    Document mainDocument = application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

    if(elements.Size > 0)
    {
        //Only 1 room should be selected
        return Result.Failed;
    }

    Room room = null;

    foreach(Element element in elements)
    {
        room = element as Room;
    }

    if(room == null)
    {
        //A non-room element was selected
        return Result.Failed;
    }

    GetRoomDimensions(mainDocument, room);

    return Result.Success
}
```

Here is a link explaining the `IExternalCommand` in depth:

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-API/files/GUID-797F9E50-08C4-4E58-8CF0-8B4C68035409-htm.html